# Log4net RollingFileAppender not writing when application runs as a service

Tags: log4net

I have an C# application that can run on Windows 10 either as a console app or as a service, depending on a configuration parameter.  I am writing log messages using a log4net RollingFileAppender.  I'm using log4net version 4.5.  When the application runs as a console app, the rolling file gets written as expected.  When it is run as a service the file does not get written.  What can I do to get my log file?

Here's the configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<log4net>

  <appender name="TimedFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="c:/misc/HotspotControlService.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd.lo\g" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%date - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="TimedFileAppender" />
  </root>

</log4net>
```

Comment: does the service have read/write privileges to that folder/file?

Comment: I believe it does.  It's running under the local system account, and I have confirmed that that account has full control in the folder it's writing to.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, my own idiocy is the problem.  I specified the configuration file in my program by the bare file name, with no folder given.  The file exists in the same folder as my executable file.  But when running as a service, the working folder is not the folder in which the executable folder lives.  I used an absolute path for the configuration file name, and it worked.